# Correlating separate timeseries datasets

Tags: r

I want to correlate the y variables of two seperate timeseries datasets.  For example:

```
d1 = data.frame(x = seq(as.Date('2014-01-01'), as.Date('2016-01-01'), length.out = 100), y = sort(rnorm(100, mean=50, sd=10)))
d2 = data.frame(x = seq(as.Date('2014-02-01'), as.Date('2015-12-01'), length.out = 200), y = sort(rnorm(200, mean=48, sd=12)))
plot(d1, type='l')
lines(d2, col='red')
```

[image]

Grateful for any pointers on an elegant solution to this.

Comment: You've been around SO a while. Surely, you know how to ask a question even holding gold badges of good questions! What is your desired result? A graph? A dataset? And what does *correlate the y variables of two separate timeseries* mean? Running Spearman? Pearson?

Comment: Yeah those things

Comment: Huh...I named quite a bit of things.

Answer (score 0):

I think this will suffice

```
d1b = akima::aspline(d1, xout = d2$x)
summary(lm(d1b$y ~ d2$y))$r.squared
#> [1] 0.9873564
plot(d1b$y, d2$y, pch=16)
```

[image]